# What is the best way to save a List<Widget> locally so it can be read again when the app is reopened?

Tags: flutter, dart, save

I need to save a `List<Widget>`  locally so that if the app is closed and reopened I can access it again.

I've looked at Flutters own [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) for reading and writing but it seems to convert an int to a string and I'm not sure how to apply that in the context of a `List<Widget>`.

The app needs to work completely offline so I can't make http requests. Is `JsonEncode` still the best way or is SQFLite better for this task? I just need pointed in the right direction incase I'm missing something simpler and less expensive. Thank you.

Comment: Probably the best thing is JSON serialization and deserialization. Store strings in a database like Moor or Hive which are very powerful, scalable and secure

Answer (score 0):

Analyse what's the differentiating factor amongst all you widgets, for example the four widgets are Containers with different colours then the differentiating factor is the colour.

Create a list of those four colours as string, store them in shared preferences and when the app reopens, fetch data (list of colours) from shared preferences again and render the widgets.